# How can i search for a specific word(Value) in database?

Tags: java, android, database, string, sqlite

I am making an android app , which scans a text and detects if a certain word is abusive. So i want my abusive words to be stored in database (SQLite).

My question is can i check if my text contains a word which is "forbidden". Should i use loop to check if each word of the text is contained in my database ? I need this to be fast. 
Any help will be much appriciated. 
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

I want the forbidden word to be displayed or stored in Arraylist.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you save your scanned word in database, now use Like query to verify any forbidden word exists. If yes then keep that word otherwise delete it straightaway.

```
SELECT column_word FROM table WHERE id = "your_word_id" AND (column_word LIKE '%word1%' 
                OR column_word LIKE '%word2%' OR column_word LIKE '%word3%')
```

If result cursor have more than zero data then it must have forbidden word.

Comment: Thank you Rasi for the answer , but i want my forbidden word to be displayed. So if i understand correctly , this will show if a forbidden word is contained in my text , but won't show me what the word is ? Thank you again.

Comment: I think initial question was not that, although I will look into updated question.